# How to send Java collections containing subclasses to spring controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, collections

I'm trying to send collections to my spring MVC controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/postUsers.do")
public @ResponseBody ResponseDTO postUsers(@ModelAttribute("mapperList") MapperList mapperList) {
    //prints {"users":null}
    System.out.println(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(mapperList));
    return new ResponseDTO();
}
```

this is the code posting my users :

```
  public ResponseDTO postUsers(ArrayList<User> users) {
            ResponseDTO serverResponse = null;
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            // prints {"users":[{"property1":"x","property1":y}]}
            System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(new MapperList(users)));
            objectMapper.writeValue(connection.getOutputStream(), objectMapper.writeValueAsString(new MapperList(users)));
            //blabla ...
    }
```

and this is the object containing my list :

```
public class MapperList implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8561295813487706798L;

    private ArrayList<User> users;

    public MapperList() {}

    public MapperList(ArrayList<User> users) {
        this.setUsers(users);
    }

    public ArrayList<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(ArrayList<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }
}
```

and this is the users type to post:

```
public abstract class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1811485256250922102L;

    private String property1;

    private String property2;

    public User() {}

    public User(String prop1, String prop2) {
        // set properties
    }

// getters and setters

}
```

the problem is, when I output the value of the users's array before to post it to the controller, I got the following json value :

```
{"users":[{"property1":"x","property1":y}]}
```

but in the controller, when I print what I get from the request body, I only get :

```
{"users":null}
```

I also tryed with the annotation @RequestBody instead of @ModelAttribute("mapperList") and a JSONException is displayed :
*A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]\r\n*
My array list of users contains only one user that should be displayed. I don't understand why this doesn't work...
Thanks for any help !

Comment: Why does every Spring starter keep calling Spring MVC controllers "Servlets"? This is not the 1st time that I had to fix this terminology. Which bad tutorial is teaching them that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zbynek gave me part of the answer. Indeed

```
objectMapper.writeValue(
    connection.getOutputStream(),
    objectMapper.writeValueAsString(new MapperList(users))
);
```

doesn't work properly in my case

But moreover, my User class was an abstract class, with many type of User as subclasses. so the @RequestBody annotation couldn't work without specified  the object type in the Json.
I used the following annotations on User class to make it working :

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
                      @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = SubClassA.class, name = "a"),
                      @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = SubClassB.class, name = "b")
              })
```

Thanks a lot for all your answers.

Answer (score 0):

On the server side keep the `@RequestBody` annotation:

```
public @ResponseBody ResponseDTO postUsers(@RequestBody MapperList mapperList)
...
```

But this line causes problems:

```
objectMapper.writeValue(
    connection.getOutputStream(),
    objectMapper.writeValueAsString(new MapperList(users))
);
```

First it converts the object to JSON and then again uses `objectMapper` to JSON-encode the string into output stream. Try the following instead:

```
connection.getOutputStream().write(
    objectMapper.writeValueAsString(new MapperList(users))
        .getBytes("UTF-8")
);
```

or directly output to stream:

```
objectMapper.writeValue(
    connection.getOutputStream(),
    new MapperList(users))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can chnage your MapperList class definition as  `public class MapperList extends ArrayList<User>{ ..}` you dont need to define any instance variable like private ArrayList users inside MapperList class. Use @Requestbody annotation. You will be able to use MapperList as a ArrayList

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
public class MapperList{
   private List<User> users;

   //setter and getter
   //toString

}

public class User{
    private String property1;
    private String property2;
    //getter + setter
}
```

json:

```
{"users":[{"property1":"x", "property2":"y"}]}
```

in controller use @RequestBody. In that case Jackson will map your json to  ArrayList of users.

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@RequestMapping("/postUsers.do")
public @ResponseBody ResponseDTO postUsers(@RequestBody MapperList users) {
    System.out.println(users);
    return null;
}
```

no need to get objectMapper in that case. Don't forget to set content-type in request header to application/json. It required by Spring to handle @RequestBody processing.

If not working try to change MapperList:

```
List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
```